# Space Shuttle Challenger bringing back Salyut-7

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry, rescue-missions, salyut, shuttle-challenger

We know that on February 11 1985, right after the Soviets lost control of their Salyut-7 station. US Space tracking assets also started noticing that the station was starting to tumble.

[Kidnapping a Soviet space station](https://www.thespacereview.com/article/2554/1)

> US space tracking assets had immediately noticed that Salyut was tumbling out of control and, within hours, the Pentagon had come up with a plan too tempting to resist.

At that time the Challenger was undergoing some of its final preparations for an upcomming mission to launch 2 small satelites from it's cargobay into orbit. Instead different plans were made

> Why not launch it with an empty cargo bay instead, send it to Salyut-7, and snatch the station from orbit, allowing the US to steal sensitive military secrets from the Russians? Just hours after control over Salyut-7 had been lost, National Security Agency director Lincoln Faurer called President Ronald Reagan in the middle of the night to brief him about the plan. After some hesitation, the President granted his permission.

[image: Shuttle and Salyut: A Lost Opportunity]

From the article I can read that they were pretty close to a actual mission. Had it not been for Chernenko dying around the same time

> On March 10, the mission was ready to go. But then, with just hours to go in the countdown, news arrived from Moscow that the ailing Chernenko had passed away earlier that day. The news wasn’t unexpected, but couldn’t have come at a worse time. In the power vacuum left by Chernenko’s death, the Soviet response to the Salyut-7 capture became unpredictable and the Americans considered it prudent to call off the mission. Officially, the launch was scrubbed for technical reasons.

I would like to know how feasible this plan actually was.

- How would they have mounted Salyut-7 inside the cargobay of the Challenger that would allow for a atmospheric re-entry without the cargo tumbling around inside the cargobay?
- Would they have to change the landing procedure since the shuttle is much heavier with the cargo inside the cargobay?
- Has any Space Shuttle ever returned from space with a payload that heavy as Salyut-7?
- How would they have moved the Salyut-7 inside the cargobay?

Comment: (*) try 1985 for that date

Comment: The mass of the Salyut-7 (about 19 tonnes) was over the listed maximum for shuttle return, of 14.4 tonnes. I don't know if this could be finagled, it's not *that* far out of spec. The lack of suitable mounting points is likely to be a greater impediment. The presence of unsecured hypergolic fuel in the thruster system would be *very* scary indeed.

Comment: The article you linked seems to conclude there was never any US plan, only a vague suspicion on the Soviet side that they might have been thinking about one. It might be worth emphasising in the question that this is entirely hypothetical - *if* the US had tried to do this, how could they have made it work?

Comment: I suspect it would involve a good bit of work with ГОСТ-standard wrenches, hacksaws and screwdrivers stripping down the station to more manageable weight and size before attempting to pack it into the cargo bay. Likely dumping all the supplies/resources on board, and most of the more obvious but heavy hardware, say, batteries, transformers, radiators, etc.

Comment: Although the much more likely scenario is a repeat of the Lunik stunt - lots of work on site with cameras, measure tape, and all kinds of mostly non-invasive analytic equipment, leaving the station in orbit exactly as they found it a couple hours later.

Comment: Re *From the article I can read that they were pretty close to a actual mission.* Did you finish reading the article? It starts with a summary of a 2011 Russian documentary. The author of the Space Review article later goes on to debunk the story and describes as a fabrication.

Comment: Quoting the article you linked: "It takes only some basic fact checking to debunk all the preposterous allegations made in the documentary."  The only possible response to reading half an article is a down vote.

Comment: @SF. What's the Lunik stunt?

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz https://nationalinterest.org/blog/buzz/isnt-science-fiction-how-cia-stole-russian-satellite-53512

Comment: The main question that came to my mind when reading this question was "how would they design the hard points to secure the station in the payload bay?"  Did they have access to the stations designs and load data required?

Comment: @SF. very itneresting read, thankyou!

Comment: @Moo I'd think instead of exact hardpoints they could use elastic padding, say, "inflatable pillow" style, or rubber, like tires, in association with straps, screw jacks, generally techniques commonly employed when transporting awkwardly shaped cargo by a truck. What I'm more worried about is mass distribution. How tolerant was the shuttle about being more front-heavy or rear-heavy on reentry?

Comment: The threat of this 'idea' got repeated in the 2017 Russian film 'Salyut 7'. [spoiler] they even have the Orbiter ('wrong' way up with doors closed) in close proximity and everyone waving to each other lol (aside from lots of other fictional accounts in it, i enjoyed it overall) - that must have helped kick up the conspiracy theory again, after all these years

Comment: just looking at that graphic should tell you the impossibility of the idea. The station wouldn't fit inside the shuttle's cargo bay, even if you remove the solar panels first. That's not even taking the incompatibility between the docking adapters into account, which is ignored in the graphic, or the sheer mass of the station which is greater than the maximum payload capacity for the shuttle.

Comment: @jwenting it's not stated in the Q, but the illustration is originally from *Mir Hardware Heritage* (p 65), and is a mockup of what a (different, unconnected) Shuttle-Salyut docking mission might have looked like. The one hypothesised here wouldn't have involved the docking module shown in the Shuttle bay, so in principle the Salyut might (barely) have fitted in. Of course, everything else still wouldn't work!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No work was ever done on this in the Shuttle Mission Simulator (SMS), so they were nowhere "close to an actual mission". Not even any testing.

Source: I worked to some extent on all missions in the SMS from 1983-1996, including the classified ones.

Comment: Then you should neither confirm nor deny that "work was ever done on this in the Shuttle Mission Simulator (SMS)". I suggest you review the requirements of your lifelong NDA.

Comment: Only on StackExchange would an answer like that get a comment like that.  No doubt the contributor already checked with relevant authorities whether the Salyut retrieval mission is discussable. Since this isn't the first time that's been asked....

Comment: @GlennYates  I can also confirm we had no dead Zeta Reticulans. BTW, they aren't called NDAs in the DOD world.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I suspect you can only confirm they didn't have any simulated little green men... On a more practical note was the library of visual/physics models for the shuttle mission sim ever publicly listed? Found descriptions of payload bay feature modelling but not payloads. Though I think most sims I've met have had at least one goofball/testing entity in there somewhere so would expect a sanitization pass regardless of security.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Actually, they *are* called NDAs. That's the thing you signed when you were read into a program.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Well, I was being a bit cheeky in my comment, however, in general it is best to avoid ever mentioning that you worked on classified programs, especially on the open internet such as this. And, as fectin said, yes they _are_ called NDAs, and when you are given your debriefing when leaving a program, they will kindly remind you that you will remain bound to the NDA - for life!

Comment: @GremlinWrangler a list of the SMS payload models would just be a list of the shuttle payloads. The models got reused when similar payloads were reflown.

Comment: @GlenYates ... or until you're explicitly informed by someone with the appropriate authority that X has been declassified.  (Spoiler alert:  This almost never happens.)

Comment: @OrganicMarble pretty sure my forms said if I crossed the street with my shoelaces untied the FBI was coming after me. Maybe I'm misremembering, but I moved to Canada just in case.

Comment: @fectin They're CINAs, since there is no word that starts with D, it doesn't make it into the abbreviation.

Comment: Wouldn't the Zeta Reticulans be handled by NRO anyway?  *Whoops, I don't think I was supposed to say that*

Comment: @corsiKa if you saw DoD secret stuff, you signed a non-disclosure agreement (NDA). I don't know what NASA's processes look like, but the processes for classified are quite clear.

Answer (score 20):

> From the article I can read that they were pretty close to a actual mission

The article doesn't say this. It reports what *a modern documentary* claims, and then goes on to say that the documentary's claims seem to be mostly fiction or misunderstanding.

> Does this all sound too crazy to be true? Not to the makers of a Russian television documentary called “The Battle for Salyut: A Space Detective”, who present this Hollywood-like scenario as plain fact.

In short,

- most of the Shuttle missions named can be dated as being planned, or changed, well before the Salyut developments;
- there is no evidence a previous Shuttle flight ever tried to rendezvous with Salyut 7, or would have been able to do so without it being obvious to the world;
- there is no documentary evidence from the US side to support it, and only one fragmentary piece of evidence presented from the Soviet side to say that they were worried about it as a possibility.

So it seems overwhelmingly likely that there was never any plan by NASA to try and recover a Salyut, making the question of feasibility a bit moot. In any case, the article discusses this question and concludes it would have been impractical, especially for a single mission without prior preparation. The Salyut hull would have physically fit into the space in the cargo bay, but that was about all:

> Nonetheless, it would have taken a lot of work to prepare the station for retrieval. First of all, a number of spacewalks would have been required to remove appendages, such as the huge solar arrays and various antennas from the station’s hull. Next, crews would have had to unload equipment from the station’s interior to make it light enough for the return trip to Earth. The maximum payload return capability of the Space Shuttle was about 14.5 tons (not 27 tons as claimed in the documentary), but Salyut weighed about 20 tons at launch in 1982 and three years later had become even heavier after numerous resupply missions. Among a lengthy list of other problems would have been the absence of grapple fixtures and compatible docking systems to catch and enter the station. While all this would have been challenging enough for well-prepared Russian Buran crews with full knowledge of the station’s design details, it would have been an almost impossible task for a US Shuttle crew and certainly not one that could be accomplished in a single mission.

Comment: Leaving out all the technical difficulties, wouldn't this have been considered an act of war? Or at the very least, piracy - Salyut was Soviet property.

Comment: @GordonD yes - politically I think a recovery mission like this, especially of such a prominent target, would have been far too belligerent to be seriously proposed.

Comment: @GordonD, it's complicated.  Since Salyut was out of control, the US could try invoking maritime law and claiming salvage rights.

Comment: Wasn't there a TV show where Andy Griffeth built his own space program from a junkyard, and went up and salvaged abandoned satellites? Ah yes, *Salvage One*.

Comment: @Mark NASA claims ownership of all its space hardware anywhere on Earth and in space, regardless of its current state and whether someone else recovers it - see the claims for the Saturn V engines recovered from the Atlantic etc etc.  Would be hard to see how two substantially opposing stances could be reconciled...

Comment: @GordonD So you're saying that NASA would have become space pirates?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz I can imagine the pre-launch crew photograph!

Comment: @GordonD The US did this with other Soviet military hardware such as submarines that had sunk. They usually kept it secret as long as possible, but in this case the Soviets would notice immediately.